# NPE while using multipleFileUpload

Tags: vaadin8, multiple-file-upload

Getting NPE while using multipleFileUpload package in vaadin 8 application. 
Package com.wcs.wcslib.vaadin.widget.multifileupload version : 4.0

[2019-06-17T14:35:42.771+0000] [Payara 5.184] [SEVERE] [] [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=24038 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(6)] [timeMillis: 1560782142771] [levelValue: 1000] [[

java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleRequest(FileUploadHandler.java:274)
                at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
                at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
                at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2019-06-17T14:35:42.779+0000] [Payara 5.184] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=24038 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(6)] [timeMillis: 1560782142779] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[RootUIServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet RootUIServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleRequest(FileUploadHandler.java:274)
                at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
                at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
                at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)

```
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

]]

Comment: It looks like UI has been closed, gone suddenly. Is this possible in your application for some reason?

Comment: No, We have not seen it in our deployments. But got it in client's deployment

Comment: Thanks Tatu, we are using multifileupload addon to upload multiple files from client to server. After selecting files we are geting an message to upload single file and the above mentioned exception in the server log. Even a single file upload fails.